# Поиск в Твиттере, с использованием диапазонов дат

Tags: twitter

Можно ли, используя диапазоны дат, найти этот твит? -

https://twitter.com/htGOIW/status/855615155123625984 (5:52 · 22 апр. 2017 г.)

Я пытаюсь выполнить поиск с помощью следующей команды, но безрезультатно:

([ссылка](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3AhtGOIW%20include%3Anativeretweets%20since%3A2017-04-22_05%3A50%3A00_JST%20until%3A2017-04-22_05%3A52%3A00_JST&src=typed_query&f=live)) `[from:htGOIW include:nativeretweets since:2017-04-22_05:50:00_JST until:2017-04-22_05:52:00_JST]`

Comment: вы знаете, что означает JST в вашем запросе? Вы уверены, что 5:52 это именно оно?

Comment: Да, это можно проверить на других твитах. Но так же и такая команда не отображает этот твит `since:2017-04-22 until:2017-04-23` (с 22-го по 23-е число).

Comment: сложно что-то проверить, потому что для поиска нужно залогиниться, а для залогиниться нужно быть пользователем твитора

Comment: Это был вопрос к пользователям твиттера. Остальным реагировать на вопрос бессмысленно